# Android using camera app

Tags: android

In my app i'm using the camera app on the phone in order to take a picture. After taking the picture it returns back to my app. I noticed that it acts differently in different phones. In Galaxy s3 I found that after taking a picture it shows the picture and gives an option to save it (and then go back to my app) or discard (and go back to the camera app). The problem is that when the screen is rotated the app crushes when the save/discard screen appears. The only way to stop it from crushing is to take the picture without rotating the screen and keep it that way.

Is there a solution to this problem? Maybe there is a way that I can define that it won't allow rotation at this screen?

Here is the code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    //Specify target file
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    newPicName = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+app.APP_FOLDER + "/" + app.getSession()+ "_"+app.getDateTime()+ "_" +sdf.format(cal.getTime()) +".jpg";
    File imageFile = new File(newPicName);
    Uri imageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri);


    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to limit the orientation of the screen you need to specify it in your manifest…  For example:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.xxx"
        android:label="@string/xxx"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" > //this limits the screen to only portrait.
    </activity>
```

Additional Info
This is how I do it and it works for me perfectly.

```
 //instance variables
 private static final int            TAKE_PICTURE                  = 0;
 private Uri                         mUri;
 private Bitmap                      mPhoto;  

//First I create a method to capture the image.
 private void captureImage() {

    Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "profile.jpg");
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
    mUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    startActivityForResult(i, TAKE_PICTURE);

}

//Then I handle the result.

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE://this is a constant defined in my instance variables.
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(mUri, null);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            try {
                mPhoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, mUri);
            //set your photo in a screen…  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found how to disable the rotation for all screens in my app. I wish I could control the save/discard screen but it looks like I can't

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
    private File tempFile;

    private static final int CAMERA_IMAGE = 1;

    public void takePicFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (tempFile != null) {
            Log.i(""image Path : "", tempFile.getPath());
            Uri picUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile); // convert path to Uri
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
            Log.i("Picture Uri", " : " + picUri);
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, MedicationConstants.CAMERA_IMAGE);
    }
    
    
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
        
        if (requestCode == MedicationConstants.CAMERA_IMAGE) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (tempFile != null) {
                                            //do anything with image file. Store in database. Or even should add functionality of dropping
                                        }
                                    }
            }, 2000);
        }
            
    }
```

In on `onActivityResult` you should add functionality of image cropping. Please have a look at  [simple-crop-image-lib](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage). It is great library & works for almost all device.

Thanks